# DRF both Token and Session Authentication

Tags: django-rest-framework

In my project I need both Token and Session Authentication: the first one is for clients that are consuming my endpoints, and the second one is for staff users who needs to login in the django admin.
The order is:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),
```

However, I have a problem when I try to login from the client side. 
I obtain 403 error, CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.

If I disable SessionAuthentication, the login works.

Is it normal this behaviour? Do I have to change something? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use custom authentication, based on different request users such as staff and client.403 error is failed authentication due to permission denied. Also share detail if you have used any permissions.